# How to find duplicity in R?

Tags: r

How can I find number of duplicity for each value of a data frame in R?
For example:

```
a <- cbind(c(1,1,2),c(3,3,4))
a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    2    4
```

First row is repeated twice and third one is repeated once. I want to have a column with numbers (2,2,1) that states the number of duplicity for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ave(1:nrow(a), apply(a, 1, paste, collapse = " "), FUN = length)
#[1] 2 2 1
```